# Converting recursive algorithm to Iterative

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

[image]

I have done the Recursive function in Python that works:

```
def Rec(n):
    if (n<=5):
        return 2*n
    elif (n>=6):
        return Rec(n-6)+2*Rec(n-4)+4*Rec(n-2)
print (Rec(50))
```

But I can't think of an iterative one 
I am sure I will need to use a loop and possibly have 4 variables to store 
 the previous values, imitating a stack.

Comment: Don't imitate a stack, use a stack. :)

Comment: I think the goal of your math exercice is to compute a few values of Kn recursively and then to try to find a non-recursive form using the computed values. In short, it's a math problem, not a Python one

Comment: memoization would be exceptionally useful in this function

Comment: Have you ever written an iterative Fibonacci algorithm? Use the same idea.

Comment: if you consider meomization: check out [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: I suggest you to try out yourself until it hangs your brain. This'll make you a better programmer. Think more about what @user2357112  and Kenny Ostrom said.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular question, assuming you have an input n, the following code should calculate the function iteratively in python.

```
val = []
for i in range(6):
    val.append(2*i)

for i in range(6,n+1):
    val.append( val[i-6] + 2*val[i-4] + 4*val[i-2] )

print(val[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this answer:

```
$ python test.py
Rec(50) = 9142785252232708
Kist(50) = 9142785252232708
```

Using the code below. The idea is that your function needs a "window" of previous values - Kn-6, Kn-4, Kn-2 - and that window can be "slid" along as you compute new values.

So, for some value like "14", you would have a window of K8, K9, ... K13. Just compute using those values, then drop K8 since you'll never use it again, and append K14 so you can use it in computing K15..20.

```
def Rec(n):
    if (n<=5):
        return 2*n
    elif (n>=6):
        return Rec(n-6)+2*Rec(n-4)+4*Rec(n-2)

def Kist(n):
    if n <= 5:
        return 2 * n

    KN = [2*n for n in range(6)]
    for i in range(6, n+1):
        kn = KN[-6] + 2 * KN[-4] + 4 * KN[-2]
        KN.append(kn)
        KN = KN[-6:]

    return KN[-1]


print("Rec(50) =", Rec(50))
print("Kist(50) =", Kist(50))
```

Comment: I don't think we should be posting finished answers to easy homework problems.  Also, I used an even/odd check to get the starting numbers, and avoid computing half of the values.